# UIButton not calling target's selector

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have a button that doesn't call its target's selector.

When I click it, it does get highlighted. However, I set a break point at `playButtonClicked` and it never gets reached.

I'm not sure if it's being released, but I don't think so. I have ARC enabled and I can't call `retain` or `release`.

I've also tried explicitly enabling `userInteractionEnabled` but that doesn't make a difference either.

Here is my code:

```
#import "MainMenuView.h"
@implementation MainMenuView
- (void)initializeButton:(UIButton*)button withText:(NSString*)text buttonHeight:   (int)buttonHeight buttonWidth:(int)buttonWidth buttonYInitialPosition:(int)buttonYInitialPosition buttonXPosition:(int)buttonXPosition
{
    button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(buttonXPosition, buttonYInitialPosition, buttonWidth, buttonHeight);

    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [button setTitle:text forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:24];
    [self addSubview:button];
    [self bringSubviewToFront:button];
}
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {        
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

        UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"title_background.jpeg"];
        UIImageView *background = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        background.image = backgroundImage;
        background.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        [self addSubview:background];

        int centerWidth = frame.size.width / 2;
        int centerHeight = frame.size.height / 9;
        int centerXPos = frame.size.width / 4;
        int buttonYInitialPosition = frame.size.height / 2 + frame.size.height / 20;
        int buttonYOffset = frame.size.height / 7;

        // init buttons
        [self initializeButton:playButton withText:@"Play" buttonHeight:centerHeight buttonWidth: centerWidth
        buttonYInitialPosition:buttonYInitialPosition buttonXPosition:centerXPos];
        [playButton addTarget:self action:@selector(playButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
    return self;
}
- (void) playButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Play Button Clicked");
}
@end
```

Comment: what is in your log message?

Comment: There are no crashing and no log messages. It's simply not calling the target function.

Comment: do this in your viewDidLoad method, se log message

Comment: do not do this in super init method

Comment: I'm not doing it in the super init method. This is my viewcontroller's view.

Comment: set break point if it comes to your function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code isn't doing what you think it is.

When you pass `playButton` in to `-initializeButton:...` and then immediately create a new button and assign it to that variable, you're no longer operating on the value that `playButton` points to.  So when you call `-addTarget:action:forControlState:` afterwards, you're assigning a target to whatever `playButton` happens to point to, which is not the button you just created and added.

Passing a pointer is done (by default) *by value*, which means that you only have the address that the pointer held, not a reference to the pointer itself.  So you can't change the pointer itself, only the object it points to.  You can pass the pointer *by reference*, if you want to modify what it points to; or you can restructure your code so that you're always acting on the pointer directly—for instance, you could just use an ivar or property and have your initialize method set that property.  Or you could return the button and assign it to your variable or property.

Answer (score 4):

You are initializing the button incorrectly. A better approach is to have your `initializeButton` return the button.

```
- (UIButton *)initializeButtonWithText:(NSString*)text buttonHeight:   (int)buttonHeight buttonWidth:(int)buttonWidth buttonYInitialPosition:(int)buttonYInitialPosition buttonXPosition:(int)buttonXPosition
{
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(buttonXPosition, buttonYInitialPosition, buttonWidth, buttonHeight);

    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [button setTitle:text forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:24];
    [self addSubview:button];
    [self bringSubviewToFront:button];

    return button;
}
```

Then call it this way:

```
playButton = [self initializeButtonWithText:@"Play" buttonHeight:centerHeight buttonWidth: centerWidth
    buttonYInitialPosition:buttonYInitialPosition buttonXPosition:centerXPos];
```

Comment: To be a little more specific as to what is happening: `playButton` never gets a value. You pass nil (or whatever value `playButton` has) into initializeButtonWithText, and the create a new UIButton which you assign to the variable `button`. `playButton` never gets this value.

Comment: The answer by Seamus describes the problem well. I posted my answer to offer a solution to that problem. Another option would be to use the original method but pass in a pointer to the pointer.

Comment: thank you! your answer makes a lot of sense! :) I wish I could pick two correct answers!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should do your initialization stuff in the method:

```
-(void)awakeFromNib {}
```

It's like the `-viewDidLoad` method for custom `UIViews` in that all the nib objects have been loaded and ready to go.

Answer (score 0):

In the first line of your `initializeButton` method, you create a new Button. This new button is styled and added to the view hierarchy. This is the button that you see and that you can tap when you launch your app.

However, you apparently have another button named `playButton`. You pass it into the `initializeButton` method, but as written above, don't do anything with that reference. That means the `addTarget:` call goes to a button that you never add to your view hierarchy.